# Cannot fetch from database using NSURLSession?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I can't seem to fetch from a valid URL database.

I have the following code:

```
print("calling")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: "valid url")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        print("done, error: \(error)")
    }
    dataTask.resume()
    print("end calling")
```

However, it seems as though the print within the request does not get output at all.

The only output I see is **calling** and **end calling**

What am I seem to be doing wrong with my implementation?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it takes too long to execute ?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer based on another post:

[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053877/nsurlsession-datataskwithrequest-not-being-called?rq=1)

azimov was also right, it took a bit a time to execute.